# Why are the diagonals of the pressure tensor non-negative?

Tags: statistical-mechanics, pressure, flow, stress-energy-momentum-tensor

I understand that the pressure tensor is simply the momentum flux which makes sense to me (pressure is force per unit area which is momentum change per unit time per unit area). From this,  a simple mathematical deduction shows that the flux in any direction of the momentum component in that direction must be non-negative. But why is this the case?

Surely, there can be more flux in one direction than the other i.e. more particles with more speed coming from one direction than the other. It seems weirdly unintuitive physically speaking that a quantity's flux, regardless of the direction, is positive. Simplifying it to the one-dimensional case, this would mean the momentum flux is always positive in both directions. How can this make any sense?

I understand the mathematics but I think bridge between it and the physics is really missing for me. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

From a mechanical perspective, the mechanical pressure $p$ is the magnitude of *a* momentum density flux, but certainly does not correspond to the entirety of the non-convective momentum density flux in the system.

Recall that the mechanical pressure $p$ is related to the stress tensor $\bar{\bar{\sigma}}$ in the following way:

$$p = -\frac{\text{Tr}(\bar{\bar{\sigma}})}{3} = -\langle{\sigma_{ii}}\rangle$$

Since the mechanical pressure is a function of a stress tensor invariant, it is isotropic and does not change with respect to coordinate frame rotations (as you point out). However, the net momentum density flux between control volumes is not always zero because you have additional momentum density flux contributions from both external forces $\vec{f}$ and the deviatoric component of the stress tensor $\bar{\bar{s}}$.

Comment: By pressure tensor, I guess I meant stress tensor as that is the way the book I am using your refers to it. In fact, the book shows that it is indeed a momentum flux. I am using Chapman and cowling.

Comment: Although I can't say for certain without a direct definition from that reference, the tensor you are referring to might be what I often call the momentum density flux tensor $\rho u_i u_j$, where $u_i$ is the $i$th component of the velocity. The diagonals of that tensor must be positive, as $\rho u_i u_i$ is always positive regardless of the sign of each $u_i$.